# OpenCV iOS seamlessClone function gives memory error

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm trying to use seamlessClone OpenCV function on iOS, but I'm always getting an EXC_BAD_ADDRESS error.

Here it is the code:

```
Mat output;
seamlessClone(warped_frame, backgroundFrame, warped_mask, center, output, 1);
```

Also tried with:

```
Mat output = Mat::zeros(backgroundFrame.rows, backgroundFrame.cols, backgroundFrame.type())
seamlessClone(warped_frame, backgroundFrame, warped_mask, center, output, 1);
```

It gives a memory error when allocating output inside seamlessClone function.

The types and sizes of the input params are:

```
Warped frame type: 16
Background frame type: 16
Warped mask type: 16
Warped frame size: [338 x 338]
Background frame size: [338 x 338]
Warped mask size: [338 x 338]
Center point: [154, 293]
```

Type 16 is CV_8UC3.

From the function documentation:

```
@param src Input 8-bit 3-channel image.
@param dst Input 8-bit 3-channel image.
@param mask Input 8-bit 1 or 3-channel image.
@param p Point in dst image where object is placed.
@param blend Output image with the same size and type as dst.
@param flags Cloning method.
```

Everything seems fine.

Any clue on this?